# What's the usages of hyphen("-") in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We all know that when we use hyphen after the command `cd`, we will change to the previous working directory; and when we use hyphen after the input redirection `<<`, the bash will ignore the leading tabs (but not spaces) in the here script. The output from the cat command will not contain any of the leading tab characters. Is there any other usages of the hyphen character? I'm a fresh man in linux, please show more.

Comment: A hyphen (used alone) generally signifies that input will be taken from `stdin` as opposed to a named file. (it's use, and any alternate use will be specified in the `man page` for each individual command)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I don't think that's a shell feature *per se*, though. I can't think of any builtins that support that.

Comment: There are plenty of other uses of hyphens; consider `read -r`, for example, or `${foo-bar}`. What exactly are you looking for? What do you need a comprehensive list of uses of hyphens for?

Comment: True enough, it's just something that has always been there and is so engrained in the way things are done, the precise origin isn't immediately apparent `:)`

Comment: Over and above the previous comments - this has nothing to do programming?  Wrong site is my call here.

Comment: The shell has nothing to do with treating a hyphen as a filename; that is a [POSIX-specified guideline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) for designing utilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Lots.

I skimmed [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), this should be pretty complete. I learned some things.

Many built-in commands use a hyphen for options, like `declare`.

`--` declares the end of options to a shell builtin.

`$-` "expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation".

`-N` unary minus.

`N--`, `--N` pre and post increment operators.

`N - M` subtraction.

`N -= M` subtract and assign

`file1 -X file2` and `-X file` are file test operators

`~-` will expand to the value of `$OLDPWD`.

`-X string` are various string operators.

`-o optname` to check if an option is enabled.

`-X varname` various variable operators.

`~-N`, where N is a number, will expand to the value in the directory stack.

`arg1 -op arg2` various binary comparison operators.

`${parameter:-word}` uses `word` as the default if the parameter is unset.

`[a-d]` in a pattern match indicates a character set range.

`>&-` and `<&-` indicates to duplicate and close a file descriptor.

`<<-` indicates a here document to strip leading tab characters.

`%-` previous job.

`M-x` and `\M-` are used to display a meta character.

`C-x` and `\C-` are used to display a control character.

Readline variables can have `-` in their name.

`x-y` are a range of words when selecting from an event.

`expr1 -X expr2` boolean logic and/or test operators

Comment: with the `diff` command you can check and output and a file `./a.out | diff - checker_file`

Comment: @GustavoAdolfoMejía That's not a shell thing, diff does that itself.